# Not getting all the necessary data when going through my loop in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a page where I list all the users that sold items on different months, but each user could have sold the items on different days of the month. This is what
I'm trying to get.

```
January
user 1
user 4
user 5

February
user 4
user 2
user 3
```

I've managed to get it to list the months, but it only displays one user per month. For example

```
January
user 1

February
user 4
```

Here is my code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN items ON users.id = items.user_id GROUP BY Year(items.sold_date), Month(items.sold_date)";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$mnt = "";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row['sold_date'] != $mnt)
    {
        echo date('F, Y', strtotime($row['order_date'])); 
        echo "<br/>";
    }

    echo $row['name'];
}
```

My users table

```
id | name   | lastname        
1  | user 1 | user 1 lastname 
2  | user 2 | user 2 lastname 
3  | user 3 | user 3 lastname 
4  | user 4 | user 4 lastname 
5  | user 5 | user 5 lastname
```

my items table

```
id| name   |description         | user_id | sold_date
1 | item 1 | item 1 description | 3       | 2017-01-25
2 | item 2 | item 2 description | 1       | 2017-01-30
3 | item 3 | item 3 description | 5       | 2017-02-14
4 | item 4 | item 4 description | 2       | 2017-05-01
5 | item 5 | item 5 description | 1       | 2018-09-06
6 | item 6 | item 6 description | 4       | 2018-10-23
```

I hope I've explained properly. If not please let me know.

Comment: I think you need to add the user id to the `GROUP BY`

Comment: That just ended up separating the users so that I ended up with multiple January instead of one January

Comment: Can you put your tables in? With some data. The code doen't seem to match you output. I don;t see what the number after the user represents.

Comment: @JasonK - I've updated my question to have my table

Comment: How about the sold_date.

Comment: When using GROUP_BY, you have to provide an aggregation function on all selected column unless it will return the 1st value. Please try something like this & adapt you php code after:
`$sql = "SELECT group_concat(users.name) as name, items.sold_date  FROM users INNER JOIN items ON users.id = items.user_id GROUP BY Year(items.sold_date), Month(items.sold_date)";`

Comment: @JasonK - I've added the sold_date

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) if you want to print the ids in a single line with a delimiter.  The query would look something like this:

```
SELECT 
    Year(items.sold_date) as 'Year Sold',
    Month(items.sold_date as 'Month Sold',
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct users.id) as 'Unique User Ids'
FROM users
INNER JOIN items
ON users.id = items.user_id
GROUP BY 
    Year(items.sold_date),
    Month(items.sold_date);
```

If you are looking to get the desired results on several lines per year/month, you can just add the `users.id` column to your group by:

```
SELECT * FROM users
INNER JOIN items
ON users.id = items.user_id
GROUP BY 
    Year(items.sold_date),
    Month(items.sold_date),
    users.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This looked Like it gave the output you were looking for.

```
$sql = '
SELECT
    YEAR(I.sold_date) sold_date_Y,
    MONTH(I.sold_date) sold_date_M,
    U.name,
    COUNT(I.user_id)

FROM users 
    AS U

INNER JOIN items 
    AS I 
    ON I.user_id = U.id

GROUP BY 
    YEAR(I.sold_date), 
    MONTH(I.sold_date),
    U.name

ORDER BY
    YEAR(I.sold_date), 
    MONTH(I.sold_date),
    U.name';

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$savYM = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $curYM = $row['sold_date_Y'].'-'.$row['sold_date_M'];
    if($curYM != $savYM){
        echo '<br/>'. date('F, Y', strtotime($curYM)) .'<br/>'; 
    }
    echo $row['name'].'<br/>';
    $savYM = $curYM;
}
```